# Passing info to PHP with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, .post

I have made a js function to remove data from a database using ajax. its very basic but i want to get it to work before i add anything else the function is below:

```
function removeAd(ad_id) {

    $.post('remove.php', {id: ad_id});

};
```

I use php to build a page and create links that use this function:

```
<ul id='categoryorder'>

<?php while ($item = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) { ?>

<li id="advert_<?php echo $item['display_id'] ?>"><div class="<?php echo $item['ad_type']?>"><a href="javascript:removeAd('<?php echo $item['display_id'] ?>')" >Remove</a></div></li>

<?php } ?> 

</ul>
```

it builds the page fine and creates remove links within divs that have a href of javascript:removeAd(id) with the id being the id that relates to that div in a database eg:

```
<li id="advert_5"><div class="banner"><a href="javascript:removeAd('5')" >Remove</a></div></li>
```

finally this should send to the remove.php script which actually removes from the database the entry with that ID

```
<?php

require ('Mysql_Connect.php');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    $q = "DELETE FROM st_display WHERE display_id = {$_POST['id']}";
    $r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);

}

?>
```

I am very new to this so im quite prepared to be told that im making a stupid mistake or that this will never work! but any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: its not secure i know but that will come when i get it working plus it is never going to be published on the internet and is for internal use

Comment: and its not working at all it just doesn't remove from teh database like it should

Comment: What is value of $_POST['id']

Comment: $.post('remove.php', {id: ad_id}); this is meant to populate that where ad_id comes from the link that is clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is perfect for a good SQL injection.
But that's not the importance here, if you try to do `echo $q` does it return something ?
Do a `console.log(ad_id);` before your `$.post` to see if you send the data as well.

Comment: i thought of doing things like that but the remove.php file is an external one so it if i echo anything it wouldn't show on the page that im calling the funtion from would it?

Comment: You need to look in the developer mode ! Go in Network and you will see your page and the return

Comment: Or you do $.post('remove.php', {id: ad_id}, function(r){ console.log(r); }); it will do the trick ;-)

Comment: in the end i just created a new div and made my js function display the remove.php once complete. this is the error :               Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\JH_Front_Page_Editor\remove.php on line 7
this is the queryDELETE FROM st_display WHERE display_id =

Comment: so its say that $_POST['id'] doesn't exist but i thought that the function was meant to create this

Comment: Do a console.log(ad_id); before your $.post

Comment: I managed to get this working but I'm unsure as to how really. I when i watched the console everything seemed to be ok and now it works

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `;` at the end of the `echo` statements,

```
<li id="advert_<?php echo $item['display_id']; ?>"><div class="<?php echo $item['ad_type']; ?>"><a href="javascript:removeAd('<?php echo $item['display_id']; ?>')" >Remove</a></div></li>
```

Comment: Not an issue when doing a single echo using inline php. `<?php echo "some text"?>` is valid.